# how is kernel and user space addressing layed out on HIGHMEM kernels?

Tags: memory, linux-kernel

if a Linux 2.6.x kernel has these options enabled:

```
CONFIG_X86_4G=y
CONFIG_X86_SWITCH_PAGETABLES=y
CONFIG_X86_4G_VM_LAYOUT=y
CONFIG_X86_UACCESS_INDIRECT=y
CONFIG_X86_HIGH_ENTRY=y
```

how does the address layout change?

Comment: A very difficult question since none of those config options seems to have ever been part of the 2.6 kernel source tree.